# Attempting to make altcase. Char is derefferenced, how do I fix this?

Tags: java, char

I'm trying to make altcase. 
Most of the program works except where I ad the strings together on both the if and else statement. (where newstr = newstr....)
If this were to run, it should output
'I HoPe aLtCaSe wOrKs'

```
public class tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(altCase("i hope altcase works"));
    }
         public static String altCase(String text)
    {
        int COUNT = text.length();
        char c;
        int check = 0;
        String newstr = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
        {
            c = text.charAt(i);
            if(check == 0) {
                c = c.toUpperCase();
                newstr = newstr + c;
                check++;
            }
            else {
                c = c.toLowerCase();
                newstr = newstr + c;
                check--;
            }
        }
        return newstr;
    }
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: `c` is a `char`, it has no methods you can call.  Use the utility methods of `Character`: `Character.toUpperCase(c)` and `Character.toLowerCase(c)`

Answer (score 0):

The code should be like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(altCase("i hope altcase works"));
    }
    public static String altCase(String text)
    {
        int COUNT = text.length();
        char c;
        int check = 0;
        String newstr = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
        {
            c = text.charAt(i);
            if(c==' ') {
                newstr = newstr + c;
                continue;

            }
            if(check == 0) {
                c = (char)(c-32);
                newstr = newstr + c;
                check++;
            }
            else {
                newstr = newstr + c;
                check--;
            }
        }
        return newstr;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would call [`String.toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--) and then convert even indices to uppercase with `Character.toUpperCase(char)` and odd indices to lowercase with `Character.toLowerCase(char)`. Finally, return a new `String` based on the updated `char[]`. Like,

```
public static String altCase(String text) {
    char[] arr = text.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            arr[i] = Character.toUpperCase(arr[i]);
        } else {
            arr[i] = Character.toLowerCase(arr[i]); 
        }
    }
    return new String(arr);
}
```

On reflection, we can improve that by converting the input to upper case first, and then only changing odd elements to lower-case. Like,

```
public static String altCase(String text) {
    char[] arr = text.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
        arr[i] = Character.toLowerCase(arr[i]);
    }
    return new String(arr);
}
```

I'm assuming input isn't always strictly lower-case. If it is, then it would be trivial to skip the up-front case conversion and apply the same approach to the even indices. Like,

```
public static String altCase(String text) {
    char[] arr = text.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
        arr[i] = Character.toUpperCase(arr[i]);
    }
    return new String(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a solution without using `toUpperCase()` or `toLowerCase()`, I suggest you to try this out.

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(altCase("i hope altcase works"));
    }

    public static String altCase(String text) {
        char[] array = text.toCharArray();
        text ="";
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            text += (i%2!=0)?array[i]:Tester.utilityToUpper(array[i]);
        }
        return text;
    }

    public static char utilityToUpper(char i){
        return (char) ((i!=' ')? (i - 32) : i);
    }

}
```